# Save JSON File on clientSide in a vue project

Tags: json, vuejs2

I need to be able to save a client-side JSON file when a form is submitted. But I have the impression that it is either impossible for security reasons, or rather mysterious.

If I recap the steps:

- I submit my form,
- I save the information in my JSON file,
- this information is displayed on another Vue.js module.

The idea is not to have to set up a DB because I have very little time ahead.

I try to use FS module but since i'm full Client Side the function writeFileSync seems to not working.

Would you have a solution for this problem ?

Have a nice day